# Using gdb to compare assembly traces

Tags: assembly, gdb, arm, reverse-engineering, trace

I have a shared object file that I don't have the source for. I am interested in what happens when entering a specific function. When entering this function in a certain situation (when there is a Wifi connection available), the program reacts in a certain way; in a different situation (no connection available), it behaves in a different way. I'm trying to identify the point in the program where the external situation (the existence of the Wifi connection) is being tested, in the aim of patching the shared object file to bypass this check.

Using `gdb`, I can follow the execution of the program by hand. However, it is a pain to find by hand the point at which the execution path differ. Isn't there a way to ask `gdb` to store the sequence of machine instructions being executed (and optionally some more state, like the register contents) and to diff the sequences in both situations to determine more easily at which point the external condition is being checked?

Something relevant seems to be the `gdb record` feature, however I can't use this because the program is running on ARM and recording is not supported on this target. However, I'm not looking for any form of hardware support, because performance is not critical at all -- I would just need a way to ask `gdb` to automatize the logging of the instructions executed, much as I would do by hand by following the program execution with `ni`. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Disassembling with objdump is not helpful?

Comment: auselen: I want to diff the sequence of instructions being executed when the program runs (importantly, including the actual branches being followed), not diff the static assembly sequence.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas come to mind.

You could automate this by invoking "stepi" in a loop and use the logging feature to log gdb's output.  Then you could diff the two log files.

Or, you could do the same thing from Python, which would maybe give you better control over the format of the data you generate.

Also, I vaguely recall that this has been done before, and you could search the gdb wiki or perhaps the mailing list archives.